# How to add a CarPlay support to an existing iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, carplay

Apple announced [**CarPlay**](https://www.apple.com/ios/carplay/) feature and some of the 3rd party apps are already integrating it (Spotify, Beats Radio, iHeartRadio)

What is the first step to add a **CarPlay** support to an existing iOS Xcode project? I cannot find any information on it like adding a new target, supported device type etc.

Comment: probably the first step is to sign yet another NDA.

Comment: I do not think that this is too broad. It is a valid question, while it might not be easily answered. +1

Comment: I agree it is a valid question, i've seen worse and highly voted though, vote to Reopen.

Comment: I believe it is currently under exclusive agreements between certain apps and Apple. You will likely need to contact Apple for access to the APIs.

Comment: Here's an article you may find interesting http://macdailynews.com/2014/03/06/apples-new-carplay-api-allows-developers-to-easily-add-carplay-support-to-third-party-apps/

Comment: As of now (March 2014), Apple is only working with a few hand-selected developers for CarPlay, so even if you figured out how to hack in CarPlay support, your app would almost certainly be rejected from the App Store. I'm betting Apple will release the CarPlay API at WWDC this year. They will probably start accepting CarPlay-enabled apps once iOS 7.2 or iOS 8.0 is released (but that's purely speculation).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MediaPlayer Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html).  There are a bunch of classes in there designed for CarPlay only.  For example, MPPlayableContentManager, MPContentItem, etc.  Obviously, you won't be able to develop using it without Apple's approval.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to find any public SDK info about CarPlay since it really feels like it's in the "beta" phase of rollout before general distribution. As far as initialization goes, I suspect you'll just be making an separate `UIScreen` object that represents the CarPlay window instead of your iOS device if it's anything like how AirPlay works today. See here: [Multiple Display Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html).